# pyautogui.click() not working in web browser on specific site

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, click, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.moveTo(x1, y1, duration = 1)
pyautogui.click(clicks = 2)
```

I'm trying to automate the mouse moving to and clicking a specific location in my web browser. However, it's not letting me left click after having moved the mouse to the desired coordinates. But it is letting me right click.

And, after having moved if I use my mouse to click, that click works. Just can't get it to execute the click on this specific page. Is it possible that this site has some block to not allow me to automate this clicking?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I just tried this and it gave no error. Is there an error output or does it simply right click but not left click?

Comment: Yeah no error output. It simply will right click but not left click. 

And I don't know if this makes any difference or not but when the script is running, it seems like on the mac dock some icon that looks like a pen in python colors pops up and bounces.

Comment: Can you link the sight please or supply the HTML for the area you wish to click.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```python
import pyautogui

pyautogui.moveTo(xPosition, yPosition, duration=1)
pyautogui.click(clicks=2, button='left')
```

Tell me if it worked

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tried specifying the button and increasing the clicks. And, oddly enough, the right click works but not left.

Comment: @i_feel_dumb There might be a problem with the python version you have